# d3.js v5 changing an element from an imported svg

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, inkscape

I am a beginner to d3.js v5 and I have been battling with this all day.

I have a graphic I am constructing in inkscape that I want to animate using d3.js, but I cannot seem to change anything. A simple example follows:
The import is

> RedCircle.svg

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="210mm"
   height="297mm"
   viewBox="0 0 210 297"
   version="1.1"
   id="svg1482"
   inkscape:version="0.92.3 (2405546, 2018-03-11)"
   sodipodi:docname="RedCircle.svg">
  <defs
     id="defs1476" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="0.35"
     inkscape:cx="-244.28571"
     inkscape:cy="560"
     inkscape:document-units="mm"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:window-width="1920"
     inkscape:window-height="1044"
     inkscape:window-x="0"
     inkscape:window-y="0"
     inkscape:window-maximized="1" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata1479">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1">
    <circle
       style="opacity:1;vector-effect:none;fill:none;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#ff0000;stroke-width:0.52899998;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:1.58699999, 0.529;stroke-dashoffset:0;stroke-opacity:1"
       id="RedCircle"
       r="100"
       cy="191.7355"
       cx="105.2645" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

> index.html

```
<body>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
    <script>
        d3.xml('RedCircle.svg')
            .then(data => {
                document.body.append(data.documentElement)
            });
        var rc = d3.selectAll('#RedCircle')
        rc.style("stroke", "black");
        console.log(rc.attr("stroke"));
    </script>
</body>
```

This is supposed to make the labelled RedCircle turn black and output black. However, I am a bit lost on why it doesn't work.
I searched around quite a bit but could not really find a solution.
The error that pops up is:

```
TypeError: node is null
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: d3.xml method is async. When you are calling `d3.selectAll` it's likely not loaded yet. Put all that logic into the d3.xml's callback block (after document.body.append call)

Comment: Fantastic! So could I use await here to run the select all after d3.xml has done its thing?

Comment: Why `selectAll` for an id selection?

Comment: I'm don't really know js's promise api, sorry

Comment: the `selectAll` was a stab in the dark because `select` didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the best solution but it now works.
I made the `d3.xml` promise a variable and used `.then` to execute the image manipulation stuff.
Thanks to Coderino Javarino for pointing me in the right direction.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<body>
    <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.js"></script>
    <script>
        var img = d3.xml('RedCircle.svg')
            .then(svg => {
                document.body.append(svg.documentElement)
            });
        img.then(function() {
            var rc = d3.select('[id=RedCircle]');
            rc.style("stroke", "#000000");
            console.log(rc.style("stroke"));
        });
    </script>
</body>
```